# Clearing results but not deleting data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am still on milk when it comes to programming and my knowledge base.  Please be patient and gracious as I know my questions may not include industry vernacular.

I have a time entry form.  When the user submits their entry it displays on a table.  The user can view their entry and either update or delete their submission.

Problem 1. While testing, data submitted by user displays on the  table, this is beginning to create a very large and cumbersome table.  When the application is launch, there will be 11 people submitting daily.

Desired Added function: I would like the workflow from the form to be as follows: Populate time entry, Submit time entry, review time entry, Update/Delete/ or Confirm time entry.  Once the Confirm function is executed, I would like the record to clear from the  table display but remain within the mysql database.

Regarding the desired confirm function:  I have tried inserting code within my app that creates a button that would reset/remove the data from the  table.  The button was there.....the desired function....not so much. "onclick" nothing would happen.

Below is the code were the delete action lives, this is where I tried inserting the reset/remove action.

```
<a href ="action.php?delete=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class= "badge badge- 
danger p-2" onclick="return confirm ('Do you want to delete this 
record?');">delete</a>
```

---

Below is the action.php code:

```
if(isset($_GET[ 'delete'])) {
        $id=$_GET[ 'delete'];

        $query= "DELETE FROM timex WHERE id = ? " ;
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
        $stmt->execute();

        header('location:crudApp.php');
        $_SESSION[ ' response ' ] = "You have deleted a record" ;
        $_SESSION[ ' res_type' ]="danger" ;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please focus on one problem only. You can ask a separate question for a second problem. Also, the code you provided does not show any attempt to implement the functionalities you are discussing in your text. In order to help, you should provide the code which fails to implement what you want, but has the attempt. Then explain exactly what goes wrong/unexpected, and we could help you out  with that particular issue.

Comment: Offtopic: One tip separate the javascript code from the html code as much as possible..A other tip [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) also might be usefull to learn as it allowes you to do some things much more easy.